# Manga about a high-ranking female adventurer with twin daughters and different-coloured eyes

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character (a mother of twin daughters) is semi-immortal and is the highest ranked adventurer in the world. She is super doting of her two daughters and is merciless to anyone who tries to talk to them.

She is white haired (same with the daughters) and has two different colored eyes. Non full color.

Comment: While this is **not** the one you're asking about, this premise sounds quite similar to the current-season anime _I've Been Killing Slimes For 300 Years And Maxed Out My Level_ .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pretty sure this is *[Even Though I’m a Former Noble and a Single Mother, My Daughters Are Too Cute and Working as an Adventurer Isn’t Too Much of a Hassle](https://myanimelist.net/manga/121509/Moto_Kizoku_Reijou_de_Mikon_no_Haha_desu_ga_Musume-tachi_ga_Kawaisugite_Boukenshagyou_mo_Ku_ni_Narimasen_comic)*.

> A world where monsters run rampant. A noblewoman falls from grace and loses everything after being falsely accused. But, she started a fresh life as an "Immortal." She became an adventurer capable of defeating disaster-rank monsters and taking the heads off ancient dragons with a single swing of her blade. However, behind that cool exterior... beats the heart of a ridiculously over-indulgent mother!?
>
> "What should I do, my daughters are just too cute!?"
>
> She wields her deadly sword for the sake of motherly love! Ogres flee and dragons tremble at the sight of this overpowered adventurer! The fantasy adventure of the Doting Mother Sword Demon begins now!

The MC is a B-rank adventurer swordswoman named Shirley. She's a "semi-immortal with different coloured eyes and snow white hair," and also a single mother with two 10-year-old daughters, to whom she's extremely devoted.

She was once a noblewoman, but because of her "physical features," she was treated as the "manifestation of an ancient fear" by the nobility of the Empire, and abandoned and betrayed. As a result, she felt she had no other recourse than to be become an adventurer, which enables her to earn a comfortable living and spend plenty of time with her daughters.

The manga is mostly in black & white, with a few pages in full colour.

[image]

[image]

Comment: ... Now that's a title.

Comment: It's worse than _I Don't Want To Die, So I'll Max Out My Defense_, _That Time I Got Reincarnated As A Slime_, and _Is It Wrong To Pick Up A Girl In A Dungeon?_ put together!

Comment: @BruceWayne I have to imagine it sounds better in Japanese?  Maybe just wishful thinking...

Comment: The premise sounds interesting, even if the title gives it away. Novels in English used to have been long title, in any case.

Comment: @BruceWayne: Side note, the long titles are apparently an artifact of their beginnings as light novels which, being listed by title on websites, felt a pressure to pull in viewers as quickly as possible, which led to the overly descriptive titles. Now, it's just what you do.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots haha, so sort of like a click bait title. Interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the main character a former noble?If yes, the name of the title is"

Even Though I'M A Former Noble And A Single Mother, My Daughters Are Too Cute And Working As An Adventurer Isn't Too Much Of A Hassle"

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain a bit more how it matches the description given in the question? See the other answer here for an example of how to do that.